# Page not Found is not working with nested routes in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, nested-routes, custom-error-pages

I have setup the routing as:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route path="/topic" element={<Topic/>} >
           <Route path=':name' element={<SubTopic/>} />
      </Route>
     <Route path='/*' element={<PageNotFound/>} />
  <Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

It is working fine until I check for page not found.
At url bar `localhost:3000/topic/product` can move to SubTopic page and can fetch the topic name using useParams. But if I type `localhost:3000/topic/product/random` it is not going to page not found. it is showing error at console as undefined data.
How to render to page not found?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe with this minimal [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/page-not-found-is-not-working-with-nested-routes-in-react-router-dom-v6-tkumq9) demo. I suspect the issue is caused by one of these routed components you are rendered, specifically the `SubTopic` component. Can you edit the post to include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using as part of your complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change:

```
<Route path='/*' element={<PageNotFound/>} />
```

to:

```
<Route path='*' element={<PageNotFound/>} />
```

The route that has a path * is a catch all route. If you have the /* then it would try to route "Home" and then the catch all route.

Comment: No it is also not working.